# How to add the Html helper extension to this grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I need to create and html helper extension which takes boolean and returns string depending on the boolean value

```
    public static string ConvertToString(this HtmlHelper helper, bool val)
    {
        if (val)
        {
            return "Y";
        }

        return "N";
    }
```

The problem is how can I intergrate this to the below telerik grid column. I want to make the o.MultipleCurrencyFlag which is a boolean should give me Y or N

```
       <% Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
        .Name("grid").Footer(false).Columns(columns =>
        {
                columns.Bound(o => o.MultipleCurrencyFlag).HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "currency"}).Title(Html.Resource("MultipleCurrencyTableHeader"));
        }
        ).Pageable(pager => pager.PageSize(25))
        .Footer(true)
        .Render(); 

         %>
```

Below code need to change it to use the Html.ConvertToString(o.MultipleCurrencyFlag)

```
columns.Bound(o => o.MultipleCurrencyFlag)
       .HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "currency"})
       .Title(Html.Resource("MultipleCurrencyTableHeader"));
```

//edit 
I also tried

```
columns.Bound(o => o.MultipleCurrencyFlag)
       .Format(Html.ConvertToString(o =>  o.MultipleCurrencyFlag))
       .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "currency" })
       .Title(Html.Resource("MultipleCurrencyTableHeader"));
```

I cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using server binding, this will do it for you:

```
columns.Template(o=> { %>
                           <%=Html.ConvertToString(o.MultipleCurrencyFlag)%>
                  <% })
       .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "currency"})
       .Title(Html.Resource("MultipleCurrencyTableHeader"));
```

-Josh